# Parallelize for loop python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code...but takes some time as it loops through each iteration and storing each data frame into a list. Then this list of dataframes are then concatenated together. Is there an easy and a faster way to achieve the end result

```
        
        size = len(List)
        i=0 
        dfs = []
        for i in range(size):
            abc = List.iloc[i]['xyz']
            if abc.find('&')!=-1:
                abc = abc.replace('&', '%26')
            
            df = myfunction(abc)
            dfs.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly using options built into pandas would be more useful for whatever you want to do. In this case, it is sort of hard to know what you want to do without more info. Take a look at this:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

In general, for simple things you can usually avoid for loops altogether through map, or using operations on arrays.

I think it is more likely that the most efficient thing to do here in terms of your time is to read over the pandas documentation for a simple way to do what you want rather than trying to parallelize anything (usually nontrivial).

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your code does.  What you've posted is incomplete, but we can infer that you want to "escape" the `&` characters in one column of data, pass each value in that column to `myfunction()` (which you haven't shown so we can't optimize!), and concatenate all the results.

The first part is trivial to optimize for a speedup of more than 10x, though it won't help the `myfunction()` part:

```
abc = List['xyz'].str.replace('&', '%26')
```

Now you have a Series of all the `abc` values you need to pass to `myfunction()`.  Next:

```
dfs = [myfunction(x) for x in abc]
```

Those two lines of code will give you the same result as your original code.  Whether they are much faster or not depends on what fraction of your time was spent in `myfunction()` (see [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).